# Professionalism at piano playing

Tags: piano, fingering, keyboard, acoustics

What is the easiest way to get professional on the piano and what is the trick behind using two different hands to play several different notes with different fingers. How is the memory improved by this exercise.

Comment: Hi! This is hard to answer right now since there are several different questions and more detail would help. Please check out [the kind of questions covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to get concise, objective answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Then please use the "Edit" button to focus on one question and maybe tell a bit more: are you looking for advice on technique? career? how to pick a conservatory?

Comment: Also, let's define what "professional" means. Be aware it's a big ask, like "what's the easiest way to become an Olympic athlete," and if there were _any_ "easy" way, everybody would be doing it.

Comment: In addition to @AndyBonner 's direction, "how is the memory improved by this exercise" seems to be a question for the Psychology site.  Unless you meant: "how does memorizing the notes help one to coordinate playing different notes with different fingers using two different hands", which is a question on piano practicing technique.

Comment: @Cornelius I'd *decline* (in the sense of making the concept smaller in perception) what Andy correctly said above: a professional athlete doesn't have to be an Olympic, and vice versa. We could even discuss (but this isn't really the place) the difference between "being professional" and "being **A** professional". I know a lot of people that may belong to one of those categories, both, or even none of them. *In any field*. Not to mention the awkward category of "certified" professionals, which are sometimes self-proclaimed. In any case, your question is misguided, and for lots of reasons. »

Comment: @Cornelius » First of all, as said above, the term "professional" is extremely ambiguous for any field, and especially for the vague concept of profession when dealing with music and arts in general. Then, if you want to "get professional" (whatever it may mean), looking for the "easiest way" is a terrible approach in the first place. Professionalism requires lots of time, hard work, sacrifices and efforts; it may be fun (if you're doing  it in ways compatible with your concept of "fun") or "simpler" (compared to other methods), but it's just a matter of personal opinion and perception. »

Comment: @Cornelius » There are no "tricks"; at least, no generic ones; not for becoming a "professional" in any field, and not even for slightly more specific aspects like "using two different hands" (besides, is there anybody having two identical hands? ;-) ). If there's any possible wide and generic suggestion about learning (leaving out the "professional" concept), I'd say that there is only one valid principle: learn more about yourself, so that you will know the best way to make yourself learn. Including learning more about yourself :-)

Answer (score 1):

> what is the trick behind using two different hands to play several
> different notes with different fingers

I'm very much a beginner at trying to play the piano, so this may be wrong, but afaik there is no *trick*. But there are things you can do to shall we say "ease the pain":

- I found [this technique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cmYRz1adfLk) very helpful
- I installed EasyABC on my laptop, then typed in the scores of the simple tunes I want to learn. Then, using the % (comment) sign in EasyABC, I can disable one hand in the score, and have a simple means of playing back to me only the hand I'm struggling with and for which I need a known good sample. Master one tiny bit at a time, even maybe just one measure, one hand at a time, then bolt it all back together a bit at a time. EasyABC also lets one change the tempo very easily. As far as this beginner (aged 67 I might add....) is concerned, there's no trick, just plug away at it. (Starting really simple of course: I have Thompson's old material from the 1930s.)

**EDIT:**

Aaron asked-

> Please add a description of the video in case it is sometime taken
> down and the link becomes meaningless.

The creator of the video (YT handle "Piano Superhuman") provides a short piece to play, but suggests the technique for any piece one wants to learn. These are the steps:

1. Get good at each hand's part separately, a small section at a time
2. Get good at the rhythm, just tapping it on your legs with both hands
3. Play the rhythm using only your thumbs, eg just say a C on each hand
4. Then play the rhythm with say the left hand, and the notes with the right
5. Swap: notes on the left, rhythm on the right
6. Play both
7. Do that for longer and longer chunks

This is the music he provides, but as I said I'm using this method with Thompson's beginner pieces, Music Land, Patterns and so on.

[image]

CAVEAT: This is obviously nowhere near touching on professional: I am right at the bottom of the piano-playing spectrum, probably not yet even *on* the spectrum ;)

Comment: Thanks Very much. Really helpful.